# Is there any online link for drawing / graphing without coding yourself?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, online, drawing

Is there any tools or website that help drawing and graphing just by draw it out in a draft, then make it a file of image, then upload the image and get the latex code for it ? In addition, is there any way to draw the illustrations kind of like this without writing the code yourself ? Thanks.[image]

Comment: If you draw your image as vector graphic, you can use svg2tikz to convert it into tikz code. The code will be ugly! If you want a better quality result, read a TikZ tutorial, your graphic should be doable with just some basic tikz.

Comment: My experience is that, with the power of AI, writing Ti*k*Z code is quite easy. For example, GitHub Copilot is very capable of helping you finish the graph, especially for graphs with strong patterns.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz is Inkscape a good tools for my purpose ?

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry but it's not free right ? Do you think Inkscape a nice tools to solve my issue ?

Comment: @PermQi As good as a graphical tool is gonna get  - the resulting code will still be ugly.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have no choice since I am spending all my time for my project, the theory such as definition, example, theorem, proof, while consulting many different reference books. I really have no time to learn drawing a figure, and I don't even know how long I will have done for the code of a nice single figure, since the last time I tried it, it got me all an afternoon for just a simple circle, ellipses and lines. Really got no choice now, mate

Comment: @PermQi If you don't have time to learn latex drawing methods, then choose whatever program you are already familiar with, draw your graphic there and include it as image in your document.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz indeed I intend to draw figures by hand, but I still want to find a chance to make my project better so

Comment: @PermQi A good handdrawn figure can be much better quality than a low quality latex figure.

Comment: @PermQi Yes, GitHub Copilot is indeed not free. Hope you have the opportunity of exploring the art of Ti*k*Z when you have time :-)